# Chain slipping at specific chainring angle

Tags: derailleur-rear, drivetrain-slipping, 1x11, chainring-oval, dtswiss

1x11 road bike suddenly starts “slipping” gears without fully jumping gears. I noticed that, only when pedaling backwards in the bike stand, it happened in 180 degree intervals at a specific part of the chainring. When I checked the chainring (Stone 52t oval) it looks straight, no broken teeth. Reinstalled crankset (Rotor 3D24), cleaned hub (DT350), cleaned and reinstalled rear derailleur (Shimano ultegra 7000). Stays the same— can shift through all gears and it only skips when ridden, but the skipping is pretty bad.

Before I resort to buying a new chainring, is there something else it could be? Since it happened while riding, I just assumed it couldn’t be sudden warping of the chainring or something. I don’t see any wobble in the crank spindle.

Comment: Can you add a clear photo of the chain ring showing the teeth?   Pop the chain off for the photo.  Also, check your chain for wear/elongation - if you don't have the tool then try moving two adjacent links - do you feel play?   What's the mileage on your chain and bike, approximately?

Comment: Being a 1x11 gut feeling would be this is almost normal.  Depending on where you are in the cassette at the time, there could well be enough chain angle to cause it to move to smaller gear while back pedalling.  The chain want's to go as straight as it can and while back pedalling, it doesn't have the Rear Mech to hold it in place.